# can server and client made in different language communicate with each other?

Tags: java, php, sockets

I have a server which is made using php, and it is listening to the `ipaddress1` and `port1`, then I have a client made in java, it connects to the server using `ipaddress1` and `port1` using the `Socket s = new Socket(ipaddress1, port1);`, can this server and client communicate with each other?

Comment: YES - they can, how else should your browser communicate with every server on the internet, not everyone has the same system running.

Comment: you mean if the ip and port is correct, they should communicate with each other?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can. You have two options:

1. Use a format like XML or [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or [protocol buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) that has libraries supporting it in both languages, or
2. Just send raw bytes through the socket, and write your own format encoders and decoders in both languages.

Fundamentally, what goes through a socket is byte data, and bytes are the same in any language. The only thing that would give you trouble would be if you wanted the client to use a Java-only format like an `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: For option 2, I would just add:  use a text (not binary) based protocol:  different platforms might represent binary numbers differently.

Comment: @Curt: True if you're sending, say, an `int` in binary format (because of endianness). But sending **bytes** is as safe as text.